# Decorate imported React component with higher order component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, decorator

I know how to decorate a component before exporting it like this:

```
export default ButtonDecorator(MainButton)
```

But if I try to make a index to import it and decorate it differently for some cases. It wont work.

Here is the example of the index:

```
import MainButton from './main/main_button'
import BackButton from './back/back_button'

import { ButtonDecorator, LinkDecorator } from 'decorators'

export {
    ButtonDecorator(MainButton) as MainButton,
    LinkDecorator(MainButton) as MainHrefButton,
    BackButton
}
```

And the higher order component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

let Btn = InnerComponent => {
    class NewBtn extends Component {

        constructor(props) {
            super(props)
        }

        render() {
                return (
                    <button onClick={this.props.onClick}>
                        <InnerComponent disabled={this.props.disabled} />
                    </button>
                )
        }
    }

    return NewBtn
}

export default Btn
```

What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know [`export`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export) requires a name (variable), and not a function invocation. Try this:

```
const ButtonDecoratedMainButton = ButtonDecorator(MainButton);
const LinkDecoratedMainButton = LinkDecorator(MainButton);

export {
    DecoratedMainButton as MainButton,
    LinkDecoratedMainButton as MainHrefButton,
    BackButton
}
```